# Common columns to several table in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I was wondering if there is a smart way of having several common columns to different tables in CakePhP. I could use a common table having relationships to these tables, but is there a behavior or similar mechanism for which I can have:

Users
Customers
CommonPersonalFields

And have some common fields in the third table, fetched automatically by cake. In this way you could also have common views for those fields, included in the other tables views.

Comment: I interpret your question as: "Here's the standard way that everyone does this thing, and the way that's recommended literally everywhere, but how can I do it some OTHER, non-standard way?"  If that's not the case, you might want to clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: That's a way of seeing it. With an alternative way, you could avoid setting up relations directly and better reuse code. Maybe I'm overcomplicating this, and the linked model is the way to go. But in this case, should i add a column with the table name, i.e. in CommonFields have related_table_id and related_table_name?

Comment: Where are you in the process of this project? Specifically, is that database design finalized? The tables don't sound normalized. Is CommonPersonalFields EAV? Cakephp works best with a normalized database model (with the additional caveat of not having a composite primary key.) If your design is final, please give more detail regarding the columns and sample data of CommonPersonalFields as it relates to the other two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done with [Model Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) in CakePHP. In this scenario, your models would be `User`, `Customer`, and `PersonalData`, and your associations are `User hasOne PersonalData`, `Customer hasOne PersonalData`, and if you want the association to be linked from both directions, `PersonalData belongsTo User` and `PersonalData belongsTo Customer`.

Comment: Maybe my description wasn't clear, I havo to admit it, but that's exactly what I meant with linked table. Is there an alternative?

Comment: There is not, as far as I have ever heard of.